# REST api design for variable length nested paths

Tags: rest, api-design

I need to design an API for a resource that is nested under one or more namespaces.

For example:

```
   / +
     |
     +--- namespace1 
                |
                +-------- namespace2
                             |
                             +---------------- resource
```

where I can possibly have 0 to N namespaces.

What would be the recommended way to represent such a resource? I have considered the following approaches:

1. represent the namespace path in the URL. e.g:

   ```
   GET /resources/namespace1/namespace2/resource
   ```

- Pros: I find this the most readable
- Cons: Still have some issues representing this approach in Open API (3.0) and in some framework DSLs. Also, something feels wrong with namespaces being under "resources"

2. represent the namespace as a query parameter:

   ```
   GET /resources/resource?context=/namespace1/namespace2
   ```

- Pros: easy to declare in Open API and DSLs
- Cons: To my eyes, it's a little noisy

3. represent the namespace as a header:

   ```
   GET /resources/resource
   Context: /namespace1/namespace2
   ```

- Pros: easy to declare in OpenAPI and DSLs, a less noisy than #2
- Cons: Not sure if I like the namespace hidden in the header

Is there a recommended approach for such a problem, or are there any additional patterns I may be missing?

Comment: For me it is not to clear how to answer this. You wrote nothing about how the resources and namespaces are related or if you want to manage those relationships with your REST API. Just to mention it is not necessary to have 1:1 relationship between your web resources and domain entities. You can have a lot less or a lot more web resources than domain entities depending on what your REST API wants to support. It is more like having 1:1 relationship between web resources * HTTP methods and operations. So first I would clarify what operations I have if I were you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree, #1 is the most readable, and if the technology you're using makes that easy to work with, it's worth considering. However, it's likely to result in work on the client side to form the API call correctly, which doesn't make the API particularly discoverable or documentable.

#3 is really just a variation of #2. You've only chosen to express the namespace in the header instead of a query parameter. In either case, it doesn't make the client have to assemble the URI, but clients would probably prefer to send a "clean" request for a URI than add in headers.

Things like "scope", "context", "namespace", and "hierarchy" all lend themselves to being a query parameter. This makes #2 palatable despite your reservation.

This seems like a case of [KISS](https://simpleprogrammer.com/kiss-one-best-practice-to-rule-them-all/). REST doesn't specifically cover this case.